# Phalcon database migration revert/rollback

Tags: php, database-migration, phalcon

I would like to revert/rollback changes made to the database as part of the Phalcon devtools migration command in case of an upgrade problem.

In the migration file, it looks like this should be possible using the `public function down()` method.  However, I can't seem to get this to run.  There isn't an obvious rollback command, only "generate" and "run" (as of Phalcon devtools 1.3.4).

I have done a quick search through the devtools code on git, specifically the Migration.php code here: https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/master/scripts/Phalcon/Mvc/Model/Migration.php .  There are calls to the `up()` but no mention of `down()`.

What would be the recommended way to achieve rollback functionality here?

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for, but we have dozens of phalcon projects and we ended up using phinx for our migrations for better support

Comment: I've skimmed the phinx docs and it looks like a more robust solution for sure. Thanks David.

Comment: What I like about Phalcon migrations is that you can alter the database directly, and then generate the migrations automatically. In other migration systems I've seen is the other way around: you write the migrations and then apply them to the database, but there's no automatic generation.

Does phinx have automatic generation?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/migrations.html#running-migrations) mentions

> If you specify a target version, Phalcon will run the required migrations until it reaches the specified version.

It references the `--version` parameter you can use in your migration run command :

```
phalcon migration run --version=1.0.1
```

Depending on the current database version stored in `.phalcon/migration-version` it will either use up or down to reach the version 1.0.1

For example, given that command and assuming we have migrations 1.0.0, 1.0.1, and 1.0.2 :

- if migration-version doesn't exists, it will run the up methods from migrations 1.0.0 and 1.0.1
- if migration-version is 1.0.2, it will run the down method from migration 1.0.2